MATLAB fittype errors: What’s wrong with this amplitude fit?
My goal is to use amplitudefit A(omega) in MATLAB, what's wrong with the command?
I tried this:
%2 amplitude fits 1x for m=2 & 1x for m=7 
%x-axis = f=1/T (frequency) 
%y-axis = A (amplitude) 
%-------------------------------------------------
------------------------ 
%@ is an anonymous function  
%b is an unknown coefficient  
%z is an independent variable  
%z is a dependent variable bc its dependent on the other independent variables x & y 
% b is missing => import! 
% if necessary change Q later if diagram changed! 
%note: b=F_0/k but that has no relevance here   
A(omega) = fittype( @(b,Q) b*(1/sqrt(1-((omega)^2/(omega_0)^2)+ (((omega)^2)/(Q^2* (omega_0)^2)))),'independent', {'omega', 'omega_0', 'Q'},'dependent', 'A' );

If necessary, import %workspace Q

for m=2: Q=0.79 assumed as the highest value & measurement bit strangely plotted

for m=7: Q=0.48



workspace: omega_0 = 2.6 (1x1 table)
omega = the following 20x1 table:

1.49027052700000
3.89336639800000
3.51230425100000
3.14786967400000
2.99047619000000
2.86888990400000
2.80357142900000
2.72097053700000
2.64532434700000
2.61666666700000
2.56326530600000
2.50698602800000
2.46952418400000
2.41724403400000
2.32937685500000
2.23885918000000
2.08915502300000
1.97174254300000
1.84380505000000
1.74687065400000

Error message:

amplitudenfit
Error using fittype>iDeduceCoefficients
The independent variable omega   does not appear in the equation expression.
Use omega   in the expression or indicate another variable as the independent variable.
Error in fittype>iCreateFromAnonymousFunction (line 516)
obj = iDeduceCoefficients(obj);
Error in fittype>iCreateFittype (line 357)
obj = iCreateFromAnonymousFunction( obj, varargin{:} );
Error in fittype (line 330)
obj = iCreateFittype( obj, varargin{:} );
Error in amplitudenfit (line 14)
A(omega) = fittype( @(b,Q) b*(1/sqrt(1-((omega)^2/(omega_0)^2)+ (((omega)^2)/(Q^2*(omega_0)^2)))),'independent', {'omega', 'omega_0', 'Q'},'dependent', 'A' );

The amplitude should be fitted. I tried to program the function using fittype, but errors appeared even though all variables are imported or written down
